# A polynomial is zero if it zero on infinite subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $f(t_1, ... , t_n)$ be a polynomial over a field $F$. Suppose there exist infinite subsets $X_1, ... , X_n$ of $F$ such that $f(x_1, ... , x_n) = 0$ for all $(x_1, ... , x_n) ∈ X_1× \cdots ×X_n$. Prove that $f$ is the zero polynomial.

Not sure how to start on this one!

Comment: Do you happen to know [this theorem](http://planetmath.org/apolynomialofdegreenoverafieldhasatmostnroots)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**

- Use the fact that a non-zero polynomial in a single variable over a field has only finitely many zeros.
- Induction on $n$.